# Is there a more efficient search factor than midpoint for binary search?

Tags: optimization, binary-search

The naive binary search is a very efficient algorithm: you take the midpoint of your high and low points in a sorted array and adjust your high or low point accordingly. Then you recalculate your endpoint and iterate until you find your target value (or you don't, of course.)

Now, quite clearly, if you don't use the midpoint, you introduce some risk to the system. Let's say you shift your search target away from the midpoint and you create two sides - I'll call them a big side and small side. (It doesn't matter whether the shift is toward high or low, because it would be symmetrical.) The risk is that if you miss, your search space is bigger than it would be: you've got to search the big side which is bigger. But the reward is that if you hit your search space is smaller.

It occurs to me that the number of spaces being risked vs rewarded is the same, and (without patterns, which I'm assuming there are none) the likelihood of an element being higher and lower than the midpoint is equal. So the risk is that it falls between the new target and the midpoint.

Now because the number of spaces affects the search space, and the search space is measured logrithmically, it seems to me if I used, let's say 1/4 and 3/4 for our search spaces, I've cut the log of the small space in half, where the large space has only gone up in by about .6 or .7.

So with all this in mind: is there a more efficient way of performing a binary search than just using the midpoint?

Comment: No, mid-point is the most effective way for binary-search if we know no other information. The smaller the ratio between your smaller side and your larger side, the less-effective your search is. If you're choosing 1/4 and 3/4, why not take it to the extreme? Let's choose approaching 0 and approaching 1. You are going to continually be placed in the approaching 1 side after each search step, shaving off a search size of almost 0 each time you search. This is not efficient.

Comment: Josh, can you prove that?

Comment: Of course. Let's take a collection of 10 elements. [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]. Now, let's use the extreme, and separate the section into [1] and [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]. Found that it's in the bigger section, let's go back and separate [2] and [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]. As you can see, yours falls towards an O(n) search.

Comment: That's not a proof that no such better coefficient exists. That's a proof that .99999 is a terrible coefficient. Your logic doesn't hold.

Comment: You could easily test this yourself. Graph the varying search times of binary-search midpoints and you'll quickly find that as your mid-point goes from 0.5 to 0, your scale goes from a logarithmic to linear. Doesn't take long

Comment: Yes, and I have done so. With a naive coefficient-based algorithm (where we might say the traditional binary search is a coefficient of .5) what you say is indeed true (although not as drastic as you make it - indeed a coefficient of .1 is only double the number of compares as a .5) - this does not mean that there are not more efficient methods, only that this naive coefficient manner is optimal at .5

Comment: So you want to consider approaches that are not just a constant coefficient? There's interpolation search, which is not always applicable since it's not purely comparison-based. What sort of operations do you allow?

Answer (score 0):

Let's agree that the search key is equally likely to be at position in the array—otherwise, we'd want to design an algorithm based on our special knowledge of the location. So all we can choose is where to split the array each time. If we choose a number 0 < x < 1 and split the array there, the chance that it's on the left is x and the chance that it's on the right is 1-x. In the first case we shorten the array by a factor of x and in the second by a factor of 1-x. If we did this many times we'd have a product of many of these factors, and so the 'right' average to use here is the geometric mean. In that sense, the average decrease per step is x with weight x and 1-x with weight 1-x, for a total of x^x * (1-x)^(1-x).

So when is this minimized? If this were the math stackexchange, we'd take derivatives (with the product rule, chain rule, and exponent rule), set them to zero, and solve. But this is stackoverflow, so instead we graph it:
[image: graph has a clear minimum at x = 1/2 and is symmetric about 1/2.]

You can see that the further you get from 1/2, the worse you get. For a better understanding I recommend information theory or calculus which have interesting and complementary perspectives on this.