# should the "midpoint" location of binary search alway be at 1/2?

Tags: binary-search

In the native binary search, we choose 1/2 as the midpoint to cut off half of the "workload" in linear search and the possible answers. However, if the time complexity of the check_mid(mid) function is not fixed, will 1/2 still be a fair point for the search?

For example, In the problem of finding the first bad version. let's say the time complexity of the check_mid(mid) is O(mid), the length of the array is N. When we set the midpoint at 1/2, the time complexity of linear searching the left part would be 1/8 * N^2, and the right part would be 3/8 * N^2. So, in the aspect of "workload", the division is not fair, will a factor which bigger than 1/2 be a better midpoint in this situation(1/sqrt(2) or 2/3)?

In short, my confusion is that we get rid of half of the possible cases or the cases hold half of the "workload"?  Let's say the "workload"-T means linearly checking all the possible cases. If we cut off half of T in each recursion, the worst time complexity would be log2(T). But if we cut off half of the possible cases, the worst time complexity would not be log2(T) when the check_mid(mid) function is not fixed.

[Is there a more efficient search factor than midpoint for binary search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45886098/is-there-a-more-efficient-search-factor-than-midpoint-for-binary-search)

this question is similar but its answer didn't take the time complexity of check_mid(mid) into consideration.

Comment: [Interpolation search](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search) is certainly a thing, but it sounds like you're trying to binary search a linked list and in that case you'd be better off doing it linearly

Comment: @thatotherguy edited. it is not in a linked list, the question is similar to finding the first bad version problem, but the check() function is O(mid)

Comment: If "mid" is any fraction of the length of the length of the list, O(mid) is the same as O(n), so any fraction you pick is going to make your binary search O(n·log n) and you're better off just doing a linear search.

Answer (score 0):

If you know ahead something about distribution, maybe you could find a better pivot, otherwise `1/2` think is the best for something randomly `[1,3,8,11,23..]`.Never know in which half will be and maybe in particular cases other pivot will be faster but overall the time is not the best.[for all searches].
In most of the cases binary-search is applied on unknown sequence.
 For a known distribution:exponential-grow  `[1 3 9 27 81 ...]` it's obvious that very-very lower values will be near the start(or in 1/3) so `1/3` could be fine for `lower values` and `2/3` for `higher values`. But even here, after a few iterations is hardly to made any assumption in which half it's "probably" to be (so maybe changing again the pivot to `1/2` will give a better time). The solution here is based on "good chance to guess the right half [the one with less items]" for a few iterations based on known distribution.

Comment: My question doesn't have a target value, it is similar to the problem of finding the first bad version. l have an increasing array and a check() function, I want to find the biggest num which check(num) return True. For check(k) == True, all the numbers < k, its check is True.

Comment: As I understand you asked about other pivot [other then mid] in binary-search. The answer provided is about. Now, even if you wanted to find the first-smaller or first-bigger number compared to the input_value the algorithm is still using binary-search. So my answer is also valid ! The point is that you could adapt the pivot only if you know something ahead about distribution and only for a limited iterations (just to get rid of as many items as you could made a fair guess ... then considering again mid is the best choice)

Comment: let's say the distribution is a uniform distribution.  I know the pivot should be 1/2. In the binary search, we cut down half of the workload so the worst time complexity could be log2(time_of_linear_searching_all). Thus I think the "1/2" is for the "workload" of the linear search, not the index.  If the check() is fixed, the index is also 1/2. But what if check(k) is O(k)? the left part's time / the right part's time will be 1/3, we won't cut down half of the workload each time.

Comment: First, think you wanted to say binary-search not linear.(LS check one by one till found). For uniform you may have a pattern [1,2,3,4 ...] and maybe even use a formula to go exactly.Better said random dist. and not have any hints about where to check(in firsts steps) so 1/2 is the best for all cases. Think you made some confusions about check()-index. The idea of BS is get rid on every step of half. Now if want to get rid more then half (use 1/3 but then you should know that for 1-2-6 iteration there are good chances to get rid on each step of 2/3 and you could apply this only on know seq.)

Comment: Simply, when have no hints about distribution(random and obvious sorted) mid is the best because you never know which half is to be choose. When know something about distribution, then you could alter the pivot for a few steps and after return to mid. Hope to be much more understandable now.

Comment: My confusion is that we get rid of half of the possible cases or the cases hold half of the "workload"?  Let's say the "workload"-T means linearly checking all the possible cases. If we cut off half of T in each recursion, the worst time complexity would be log2(T). But if we cut off half of the possible cases, the worst time complexity would not be log2(T).

Comment: Say[1 to 10] : Workload, and 2 to find. Iteration1: 5 Mid,[1-5][6-10]. Iteration2 W[1-5] M=3 so [1-3] [4-5] . I3 W[1-3] and M=2=Solution.  What you get rid on each step are half of impossible cases I1 [6-10], I2[4-5]. Timing for BS are best O(1) and worst log2(N). Or keep half possible of each new Workload (WStart [1-10], W1[1-5], W2[1-3]). Hope to be what you asked.

Comment: LS is O(n) which obvious is worst the BS. But BS assume sorting which consume times if sequence is not sorted. Overall sorting + BS time should be better then LS time.